# JWT for Android with secret key

Tags: android, jwt

I have to get a JWT using the SHA-256 algorithm and a secret key (for example "blablablamysecretkey").

Despite checking SO, several libraries and their documentations I don't know yet how to perform this.

If I use this library https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt (one of the most used) this is the code sample:

```
Key key = MacProvider.generateKey();
String s = Jwts.builder().setSubject("stringtoencode").signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, key).compact();
```

Since I have to use SHA-256 algorithm I guess that I should use:

```
Key key = MacProvider.generateKey();
String s = Jwts.builder().setSubject("stringtoencode").signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, key).compact();
```

My problem is that this sample (and all of the samples I've seen by the way) use Key key = MacProvider.generateKey();, and if I'm not wrong this generates a generic key. In fact this is what the documentation says:

```
// We need a signing key, so we'll create one just for this example. Usually
// the key would be read from your application configuration instead.
```

So my problem is how could I convert my secret key (string) into something of Key class?

Answer (score 2):

`MacProvider.generateKey()` generates a random secret key, which is safer than using a passphrase. Keys need to be chosen at random. Read this post if you want to know how hmac keys have to be generated https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/95972/what-are-requirements-for-hmac-secret-key

> // We need a signing key, so we'll create one just for this example. Usually
>   // the key would be read from your application configuration instead.

The text you have highlighted means that you have to persist the key in your server in order to verify JWT signature when a client sends a token. HMAC keys are symmetric, the key is used both for sign and verify

If you want to generate a `Key` from a passphrase `String` use

```
byte hmacKey[] = passphrase.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF8);
Key key = new SecretKeySpec(hmacKey,signatureAlgorithm.getJcaName());
```

Comment: The `MacProvider.generateKey*` methods already generate keys correctly.  A caller of these methods does not need to worry about that.

Additionally, your example of `hmacKeyString.getBytes()` is incorrect.  You'd be getting the platform-specific bytes as a result, when you probably meant `getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF8);`.  But even that is probably incorrect - most secure random keys, if stored as a string, are Base64-encoded.  You wouldn't need to get the bytes of the base64 string itself - you need to base64 decode it first, and the resulting decoded bytes are the actual key.

Comment: @LesHazlewood, I agree with your comment, but OP is asking specifically _how could I convert my secret key (string) into something of Key class_ The secret key is a string not encoded in base64

Comment: yes, while you have technically shown in your answer how to convert a plain 'ol string into a `SecretKeySpec` per the OP's question, that doesn't mean the OP should actually do that, and it's dangerous to not warn them of the security problems.  Per the [JWA RFC specification, Section 3.2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7518#section-3.2), HMAC signing keys **MUST** be >= 32, 48, or 64 bytes long if you're using HS256, HS384, or HS512 respectively.  "blablablamysecretkey" is _not_ a valid JWT key per the specification requirements and using a lesser key length can be dangerous.

Comment: Hi, where did you get signatureAlgorithm from signatureAlgorithm.getJcaName()?

Comment: @DarkLeonhart,  use for example `SignatureAlgorithm.HS256.getJcaName()`